# How do debug "object is not subscriptable" in Python?

Tags: database, python-3.6

It seems like I can't do this:

```
user=csv_reader[0 + row_count]
```

This code is for a university project and I'm running it on `repl.it`. If you want to take a look, it's posted here: https://repl.it/@Lia_AlexaAlexa/ConsciousYummySeahorse

```
 import csv
 def comprobando_usuario(usuario_var):
 csv_reader = open("ale.csv")
 row_count = len(csv_reader.readlines())
 while row_count >= 1:
  user=csv_reader[0 + row_count]
  useri=user[1]
  while usuario_var in useri:
    usuario_var=str(("Ingrese nuevo usuario o escribe no para 
    terminar."))
    row_count=row_count - 1
    if usuario_var in abc:
      return(0)
 return(100)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 14, in <module>
    respuesta_de_usuario= usuario.comprobando_usuario(usuario_var)
  File "/home/runner/usuario.py", line 6, in comprobando_usuario
    user=csv_reader[0 + row_count]
TypeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object is not subscriptable
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, you can't do `user=csv_reader[0 + row_count]` as `csv_reader` is a file object that you created from `csv_reader = open("ale.csv")`.

Also, you should get rid of this complex while loop and follow the doc to know how to read a file properly in Python: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files